# Unwanted mock with mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I'm doing unit tests with jUnit 5 and Mockito. In one test, I had to mock a method. Everything works fine. In another test later I'm invoking the same method but this time I don't want Mockito to do anything. Nevertheless, Mockito returns an unasked `null` value, which makes my test fail. 
I thought it was due to the first test, so I added `Mockito.reset()`. But it didn't change anything.

Do you understand what's happening behind the scene?

I ran the debug mode to have more info about the object created by Mockito. Among other infos I can read

```
invocationForStubbing: ecritureComptable.toString();
```

But I don't know where and when this method is called. 
Any help appreciated.

EDIT....
Thank you guys. I edited my post to make it clearer and also because I have now a better idea of what possibly happened:

1/ Before each test, I create a mock of the object DaoProxy and I use the mode RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS, which have mockito mock objects nested in DaoProxy

```java
  @BeforeAll
    private static void injectMockDao() {
        DaoProxy daoProxyMock = mock(DaoProxy.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        AbstractBusinessManager.configure(null, daoProxyMock, null);
    }
```

2/ For a specific test method, I use :

```java
when(getDaoProxy().getComptabiliteDao().getEcritureComptableByRef(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(ecritureBDD);
```

and reset it after use, hopping that by the next call of the all chain, Mockito won't do anything (but it didn't work) :

```java
reset(getDaoProxy().getComptabiliteDao().getEcritureComptableByRef(Mockito.anyString()));
```

3/ In another test later, i make a call to

```java
getDaoProxy().getComptabiliteDao().getEcritureComptableByRef()
```

and **Mockito - although unasked - returns a null object.**

The input of @Gavin makes me assume this is because of the RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS-Mocking of DaoProxy. Mockito mocks the nested object, but since it has no info on what it should return, it returns the default object value : null. This explains why in this case the reset didn't help.

Comment: Change your other test case. Unit test are independable from each other.

Comment: Can you add your test code to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object is marked for mocking with `@Mock` or you have used the `mock` method to create it then Mockito will return the default value for the type, which for objects is `null`.

In the failing test you could try to either provide a mocked value in the usual way, or inject a "real" instance of the object being mocked, I believe it is possible to have Mockito to provide a mocked response on a "real" instance of an object.

Comment: Thanks, I assume this is indeed what happened. See the edit of my post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make real method call in the second test then use `thenCallRealMethod()` in the second test

```
when(mock.someMethod()).thenCallRealMethod();
```